# MS SQL связи между таблицами

Tags: sql, sql-server, erwin

[image: Можно ли сделать такую связь как в таблице "Бригада"]

Делаю в MS SQL Server базу данных по этой схеме, правильно ли будет делать такую связь, как у меня от таблицы "Бригада" ?

Comment: Невозможно что то сказать по модели, не видя полностью постановки задачи. Т.е. не зная что в системе с этими сущьностями будет происходить. Вообще странно выглядит таблица руководителей отдельно от рабочих. Если человек был обычным рабочим и стал бригадиром, его что ли удалять из одной таблицы и вставлять в другую ? И система не предполагает что ли некого склада, все покупаемое отгружается сразу в бригады. А если куплена партия перфораторов и они поделены между всеми бригадами, вы эту закупку будете заводить отдельно для каждой бригады, разбивая ее на части. Ой, а перфораторы у физика купили

Comment: Я имел ввиду, можно ли чтобы от одного первичного ключа образовывалось несколько внешних

Comment: Конечно можно. как раз к этому месту вашей схемы нареканий нет